# Evitar que un checkbox se deshabilte

Tags: jquery, checkbox

existirá la forma de que un checkbox al ser chekeado con jquery por defecto, se evite que se desmarque?

Aquí simplemente valido si el nivel es igual a PIII, si lo es, se quitan las otras opciones que están dentro de un div, y hago un checked. Pero quiero evitar que el usuario desmarque por accidente dicho checkbox. Gracias!

```js
if ($('input[name="nivel"]').val() == "PIII") {
      $('input[name="0404"]').attr('checked','true');
      $('div[id="0401"]').css('display','none');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es **deshabilitar** el `checkbox` agregándole el atributo `disabled`, con esto evitaras cualquier modificación en el mismo por parte del usuario:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  if ($('input[name="nivel"]').val() == "PIII") {
    $('input[name="0404"]').prop('checked',true);
    $('input[name="0404"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('div[id="0401"]').css('display','none');
  }else{
    $('input[name="0404"]').prop('checked',false);
    $('input[name="0404"]').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="nivel" value="PIII">

<input type="checkbox" name="0404">

<button id="btn">Capturar valor</button>
```

Acá te dejo otra forma de evitar que el `checkbox` sea desmarcado sin necesidad de deshabilitarlo, como puedes ver después de dar clic al botón y que el valor del `input` sea PIII ya no se podrá desmarcar el `checkbox`

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  if ($('input[name="nivel"]').val() == "PIII") {
    $('input[name="0404"]').prop('checked',true);
    $('div[id="0401"]').css('display','none');
  }else{
    $('input[name="0404"]').prop('checked',false);
  }
});

$('input[name="0404"]').change(function(){
  if(!$(this).is(':checked') && $('input[name="nivel"]').val() == "PIII"){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="nivel" value="PIII">

<input type="checkbox" name="0404">

<button id="btn">Capturar valor</button>
```

Comment: Yo le agregaria un else, para que se desbloque si vuelve  presionar el boton y el valor es diferente de "PIII"

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez pensé en lo mismo pero preferí en primera instancia hacer únicamente lo que pidió el OP, pero tienes razón agregaré la línea de código, gracias!

Comment: Ok, gracias por las respuesta, pero si uso un disabled, cuando reciba el valor en un php si lo tomaria?

Comment: @JesusPeña te dejé otra opción para poder solucionar tu problema, la verdad desconozco si al estar disabled se envía o no el valor a PHP

Comment: Los campos disabled no se envían. Puede hacerlo con readonly o con un input type="hidden"

Comment: @MarioGuiber claro, intenté entregar una solución usando `readonly` y no funcionó, el `readonly` dejó desmarcar el `checkbox` entonces investigué y logré encontrar que `readonly` no es una propiedad para `input` de tipo `check`